# Authentication Fails with Facebook App Installed (iOS)

Tags: ios, facebook

I've just started seeing a problem with Facebook Connect authentication.  If I have version 3.4.4 of the iOS app installed, my delegate's fbDidNotLogin method gets called with an error message of "The user denied your request".  When I uninstall the FB app, the authentication works fine.  Is anyone else seeing this?  Does anyone know how I can route around this bug?

Here's my call to the Facebook object:

```
[[app facebook] authorize:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           @"publish_stream", @"offline_access", nil]
                           delegate:app];
```

Comment: Update: I get this same behavior from the latest sample app, downloaded today.  I plug in my app ID and the sample app's fbDidNotLogin delegate method is consistently called.

Comment: Could you please check out this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612701/ios-facebook-sdk-your-apps-facebook-login-is-broken

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure your application bundle id is set correctly on your app's Facebook page.

I think they just started to enforce this, which is why it just recently broke.

You should be able to change this by going into your apps settings on Facebook, and clicking 'Edit Settings' from the screen where you get your App Id. The 'Mobile Native' section will allow you to change your iOS Bundle ID to match the Bundle Identifier you have in Info.plist.

Hope this helps someone! Know that you can get this working with the latest Facebook app, and it is probably a configuration issue like the one described above.

Comment: Bingo.  Thanks for the pointer.  The iOS Bundle ID is case-sensitive, which was my problem.  What's odd is that it behaves differently depending on which FB app version you have installed.  I'd expect this type of enforcement to be a function the Facebook server-side logic, not client-side.

Comment: @Steve - This verification requires client support, as it is the client which can (and has to) send (or receive) the bundle-id for verification. The enforcement could very well be on the server-side itself. Just that they allow older version of FB app to work without having to do bundle-id verification of other apps. Otherwise every installation of iOS FB app had to be updated for any other FB-Connected app to work, which certainly is not desirable.

Comment: That makes sense, though they should have been sending bundle ID info all along.  And they apparently still don't send the bundle ID to the non-app auth implementation, so it's inconsistent.  However I'm still unhappy with Facebook for (1) failing to email developers about policy changes giving us a heads-up on what to check for (surely they know our email addresses), and (2) giving a non-descriptive error message ("The user denied you request" -- no, if it had been "iOS Bundle ID doesn't match" it would have been easy to track down).

Comment: @Corn Puff Could you please check out this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612701/ios-facebook-sdk-your-apps-facebook-login-is-broken

Answer (score 4):

I can confirm I'm experiencing the same issue here. I backtraced a bit, and I see the facebook app is opening my app with this query string in the url:

> error_reason=user%5Fdenied&error=access%5Fdenied&error_description=The%2Buser%2Bdenied%2Byour%2Brequest%2E%3F%5F

I guess unfortunately there's nothing we can do but wait :S

Comment: Unfortunately making the app connect using the webView alternative is not a solution for me. I don't think making the facebook integration worse that way (it's a lot easier for users that are logged in in the facebook app) by sending an update to apple is a good idea :(

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty obvious, but if your application is sandboxed then you need to ensure that everyone signing in with it is a 'Tester' or higher in the Facebook app settings. :-$

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666523/ios-connect-to-facebook-without-leaving-the-app-for-authorization), you can force FBConnect to use Safari dialogs instead of fast-app switching to the installed FB app.  Just comment out the block of code in Facebook.m that calls out to the FB app.

This is one way to route around the FB bug until they fix their app.  It's not an ideal solution, but it works.