# iOS Facebook connect not working when user has FB's app installed?

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

Has anyone else had this problem?  I'm getting this error when trying to authorize a user via FB, I think I've isolated it only when a user has installed the Facebook app:

fb_our_appID://authorize#error=unknown%5Ferror

If you delete the FB app from the user's phone, our app will then try to authenticate via Safari, and everything works fine.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 12):

Yup, we were getting this as well.

It occurs when your bundle identifier does not match the one configured as part of your facebook application.  Copy your bundle-id from your plist, and update the iOS Bundle ID value on facebook

https://developers.facebook.com/apps/_YOUR_APP_ID_/summary

PS: Check out facebook.stackoverflow.com for good facebook help.

Comment: Could you please comment on this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30612701/ios-facebook-sdk-your-apps-facebook-login-is-broken

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue. I Removed the facebook app from the phone and it started to work again.
I then installed the facebook app and my app kept working.
So looks like it only works fine if the app is installed before the facebook app and leads me to think it is a facebook app problem.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't tried with Safari, but I had the same error message from facebook app.

My problem was from my application bundle, which must be exactly the same as in your facebook app configuration (first field of facebook iOS app configuration).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your application bundle id is set correctly on your app's Facebook page.

check out this answer

[Authentication Fails with Facebook App Installed (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257894/authentication-fails-with-facebook-app-installed-ios?answertab=votes#tab-top)

for reference.