# FBConnect iOS sdk: unknown_error

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication, facebook, fbconnect

I'm trying to develop Facebook integration with my app.

The problem starts when the Facebook.app is installed on the device:
When a user tries to register and the app **isn't** installed, she is redirected to Safari which shows the approval page and everything works fine.
When a user tries to register and the app **is** installed, she is redirected to the app, the app seems to be processing, but no approval page appears and then it returns to my app with this URL:
`fb***************://authorize#error=unknown%5Ferror`

The Facebook.app version is 4.0.2

Any help on this subject on how to continue debugging this issue will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I see the same issue exactly. Hope someone has a solution (facebook fix probably...)

Comment: Actually this question seems to be a dup of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7572107/ios-facebook-connect-not-working-when-user-has-fbs-app-installed