# Issues in using Facebook API for iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I have downloaded the source project from
[sourcecode.](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/02/FacebookAPI.zip)

I came across many issues over there, then I changed the source header path then changed the compiler version in the project settings, then all those were solved, now there is no errors, it runs, when I click `FBLoginButton`, Facebook Login Dialog appeared but it looks empty:

[image: empty]

I don't know why, The app key and app secret key were placed correctly.
I tried with device ,if there would problem with simulator, still looks same.
What am I doing wrong, I had searched a lot, not found any solution, any ideas please tell me.

Comment: have you checked if facebook is reachable in your network?

Comment: there is no problems with network i checked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had two apps in the app store which used this old api of facebook for login and they also g=have stopped working... So most probably Facebook has stopped support for this but I couldn't fond anything official. I guess we will have to incorporate the new Api.. :/ If I find something I will post here...

Comment: @NAZIK can you please check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7604195/919545 and see if this the reason.. ? I don't have access to my MAC to check it..

Comment: I ve solved it, whats the problem is the api in that link is an old api, now I downloaded the new api and works fine with it.

Comment: Yes we also replaced the old API with the new one.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem.
I have opened a bug here : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/279606225487338
You can also vote for it, so that FB may take a look at it. Let's hope they solve it.