# Simple logging into facebook from ios app

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am trying to login into facebook with the ios app. When I click the login button in my app, it crashes.

It crashes at this point:

[self presentModalViewController:_loginDialog animated:YES];

and returns this in the log:

```
fbconnect=1&skip_api_login=1&m=m&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Fpermissions.request%3F_path%3Dpermissions.request%26app_id%3D169265183116528%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Fconnect%252Flogin_success.html%26display%3Dtouch%26type%3Duser_agent%26perms%3Dpublish_stream%26fbconnect%3D1%26from_login%3D1%26client_id%3D169265183116528&refsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Flogin.php&cancel=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html%3Ferror_reason%3Duser_denied%26error%3Daccess_denied%26error_description%3DThe%2Buser%2Bdenied%2Byour%2Brequest.&landing_serial=1&refid=9>
```

Need some guidance on this... New on linking facebook to ios

**EDITED**

```
#import "FBFunViewController.h"
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"
#import "ASIFormDataRequest.h"
#import "JSON.h"
#import "faceAppDelegate.h"

@implementation FBFunViewController
@synthesize loginStatusLabel = _loginStatusLabel;
@synthesize loginButton = _loginButton;
@synthesize loginDialog = _loginDialog;
@synthesize loginDialogView = _loginDialogView;
@synthesize textView = _textView;
@synthesize imageView = _imageView;
@synthesize segControl = _segControl;
@synthesize webView = _webView;
@synthesize accessToken = _accessToken;
@synthesize postmessage, act;

#pragma mark Main

- (void)dealloc {
    self.loginStatusLabel = nil;
    self.loginButton = nil;
    self.loginDialog = nil;
    self.loginDialogView = nil;
    self.textView = nil;
    self.imageView = nil;
    self.segControl = nil;
    self.webView = nil;
    self.accessToken = nil;
    self.postmessage=nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void) setLoginState
{
    NSString *appId = @"";  //
    NSString *permissions = @"publish_stream";
    _loginState = LoginStateStartup;
    self.loginDialog = [[[FBFunLoginDialog alloc] initWithAppId:appId requestedPermissions:permissions delegate:self] autorelease];
    self.loginDialogView = _loginDialog.view;
    [self showActivityIndicator];
}

- (void)refresh {

    if (_loginState == LoginStateStartup || _loginState == LoginStateLoggedOut) {
        _loginStatusLabel.text = @"Not connected to Facebook";
        //[_loginButton setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _loginButton.hidden = NO;
         NSLog(@"_login state: <%d>",_loginState);
         [self componentsVisibility:YES];

         if (_loginState == LoginStateLoggedOut) {
             faceAppDelegate *pdel = (faceAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
             [pdel removeFBVC];
             [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
         }
         else {
             [self loginButtonTapped:nil];
         }


    } else if (_loginState == LoginStateLoggingIn) {
        _loginStatusLabel.text = @"Connecting to Facebook...";
        _loginButton.hidden = YES;
    } else if (_loginState == LoginStateLoggedIn) {
        _loginStatusLabel.text = @"Connected to Facebook";
       // [_loginButton setTitle:@"Logout" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _loginButton.hidden = NO;
         [self hideActivityIndicator];
         [self componentsVisibility:NO];
    }  
    _textView.text = self.postmessage;
    _textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
}

- (void) componentsVisibility:(BOOL) flag
{
    NSLog(@"control in components visibility setting:  <%d>",flag);
    [lblPostToWall setHidden:flag];
    [btnCancel setHidden:flag];
    [btnPublish setHidden:flag];
    [self.textView setHidden:flag];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self refresh];
}

- (IBAction) btnCancelClicked: (id) sender
{
    faceAppDelegate *pdel = (faceAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [pdel removeFBVC];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

#pragma mark Login Button

- (IBAction)loginButtonTapped:(id)sender {

    //NSLog(@"login tapped");
    NSString *appId = @"";  //
    NSString *permissions = @"publish_stream";
    // NSString *permissions = @"email";

    if (_loginDialog == nil) {
        self.loginDialog = [[[FBFunLoginDialog alloc] initWithAppId:appId requestedPermissions:permissions delegate:self] autorelease];
        self.loginDialogView = _loginDialog.view;
    }

    if (_loginState == LoginStateStartup || _loginState == LoginStateLoggedOut) {
         [self showActivityIndicator];
        _loginState = LoginStateLoggingIn;
        [_loginDialog login];
    } else if (_loginState == LoginStateLoggedIn) {
        _loginState = LoginStateLoggedOut;        
        [_loginDialog logout];
         [self hideActivityIndicator];
    }
    [self refresh];

}

- (void ) showActivityIndicator
{
    //NSLog(@"control in show activity indicator view>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    //act = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 220, 50, 50)];
    if (self.act == nil) {
        self.act = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    }

    [self.act setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2.0, self.view.frame.size.height/2.0)];
    [self.view addSubview:self.act];
    //act.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    [self.act startAnimating];
}

- (void ) hideActivityIndicator
{
    //NSLog(@"hide activity indicator");
    [self.act stopAnimating];
    [self.act removeFromSuperview];
    [self.act setFrame:CGRectMake(-100, -100, 20, 20)];
    self.act = nil;
}


#pragma mark FB Requests

- (void)showLikeButton {

    // Source: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box
    NSString *likeButtonIframe = @"<iframe src=\"http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?id=122723294429312&amp;width=292&amp;connections=0&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false&amp;height=62\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"0\" style=\"border:none; overflow:hidden; width:282px; height:62px;\" allowTransparency=\"true\"></iframe>";
    NSString *likeButtonHtml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<HTML><BODY>%@</BODY></HTML>", likeButtonIframe];

    [_webView loadHTMLString:likeButtonHtml baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];

}

- (void)getFacebookProfile {
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=%@", [_accessToken stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(getFacebookProfileFinished:)];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)rateTapped:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"control in rate tapped with message:  <%@>",self.postmessage);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *newRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [newRequest setPostValue:self.postmessage forKey:@"message"];
    [newRequest setPostValue:@"" forKey:@"name"];
    [newRequest setPostValue:@"" forKey:@"caption"];
    [newRequest setPostValue:@"" forKey:@"description"];
   [newRequest setPostValue:@"" forKey:@"link"];
   [newRequest setPostValue:@"http://CMS/images/forlogo/" forKey:@"picture"];
    [newRequest setPostValue:_accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
    [newRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(postToWallFinished:)];

    [newRequest setDelegate:self];
    [newRequest startAsynchronous];


    /*
    NSString *likeString;


   // NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I think this is a %@ %@!", adjectiveString, likeString];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
  //  [request addFile:filePath forKey:@"file"];
    [request setPostValue:self.postmessage forKey:@"message"];
    [request setPostValue:_accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
   // [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(sendToPhotosFinished:)];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(getFacebookPhotoFinished:)];

    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request startAsynchronous];*/

}

- (void)sendToPhotosFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];

    NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSString *photoId = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSLog(@"Photo id is: %@", photoId);

    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@?access_token=%@", photoId, [_accessToken stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    ASIHTTPRequest *newRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [newRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(getFacebookPhotoFinished:)];

    [newRequest setDelegate:self];
    [newRequest startAsynchronous];

}

#pragma mark FB Responses

- (void)getFacebookProfileFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"Got Facebook Profile: %@", responseString);

    NSString *likesString;
    NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = [responseString JSONValue];   
    NSArray *interestedIn = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"interested_in"];
    if (interestedIn != nil) {
        NSString *firstInterest = [interestedIn objectAtIndex:0];
        if ([firstInterest compare:@"male"] == 0) {
            [_imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"depp.jpg"]];
            likesString = @"dudes";
        } else if ([firstInterest compare:@"female"] == 0) {
            [_imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"angelina.jpg"]];
            likesString = @"babes";
        }        
    } else {
        [_imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"maltese.jpg"]];
        likesString = @"puppies";
    }

    NSString *username;
    NSString *firstName = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"first_name"];
    NSString *lastName = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"last_name"];
    if (firstName && lastName) {
        username = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
    } else {
        username = @"mysterious user";
    }

   // _textView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hi %@!  I noticed you like %@, so tell me if you think this pic is hot or not!",
     //                 username, likesString];
    _textView.text = self.postmessage;
    [self refresh];    
}

- (void)getFacebookPhotoFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"Got Facebook Photo: %@", responseString);

    NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = [responseString JSONValue];   

   // NSString *link = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"link"];
//    if (link == nil) return;
//    NSLog(@"Link to photo: %@", link);

    /*
    NSString *adjectiveString;
    if (_segControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        adjectiveString = @"cute";
    } else {
        adjectiveString = @"ugly";
    }
    */

    // Ideally I would have liked to include this as the image for the wall post, but Facebook doesn't allow this :P
    // See: http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?id=62521&p=2
    // Update: actually now you can!

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *newRequest = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [newRequest setPostValue:self.postmessage forKey:@"message"];
    [newRequest setPostValue:@"" forKey:@"name"];
   // [newRequest setPostValue:@"via " forKey:@"caption"];
    //[newRequest setPostValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"And by the way - check out this %@ pic.", adjectiveString] forKey:@"description"];
  //  [newRequest setPostValue:@"From Ray Wenderlich's blog - an blog about iPhone and iOS development." forKey:@"description"];
   // [newRequest setPostValue:@"http://www.raywenderlich.com" forKey:@"link"];
   // [newRequest setPostValue:link forKey:@"picture"];
    //[newRequest setPostValue:@"http://www.raywenderlich.com/wp-content/themes/raywenderlich/images/logo.png" forKey:@"picture"];
    [newRequest setPostValue:_accessToken forKey:@"access_token"];
    [newRequest setDidFinishSelector:@selector(postToWallFinished:)];

    [newRequest setDelegate:self];
    [newRequest startAsynchronous];

}

- (void)postToWallFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // Use when fetching text data
    NSString *responseString = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"response string:  <%@>",responseString);

    NSMutableDictionary *responseJSON = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSString *postId = [responseJSON objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSLog(@"Post id is: %@", postId);
    NSString *msg;
    NSRange aRange = [responseString rangeOfString:@"error"];
    NSRange bRange = [responseString rangeOfString:@"Feed action request limit reached"];
    if (aRange.location ==NSNotFound) {
        msg = @"Posted to Facebook successfully";
    }
    else    if (bRange.location != NSNotFound ){
        msg = @"You have reached the maximum post limit to Facebook for today. Please try again later.";
    }
    else {
        msg = @"Error occurred. Please try again later";
    }

    UIAlertView *av = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:msg
                                                  message:@""
                                                 delegate:self 
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                        otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
    [av show];

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    faceAppDelegate *pdel = (faceAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [pdel removeFBVC];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

#pragma mark FBFunLoginDialogDelegate

- (void)accessTokenFound:(NSString *)accessToken {
    NSLog(@"Access token found: %@", accessToken);
    self.accessToken = accessToken;
    _loginState = LoginStateLoggedIn;
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
    [self getFacebookProfile];  
    [self showLikeButton];
    [self refresh];
}

- (void)displayRequired {
    [self presentModalViewController:_loginDialog animated:YES];
    [self hideActivityIndicator];
}

- (void)closeTapped {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    _loginState = LoginStateLoggedOut;        
    [_loginDialog logout];
    [self refresh];
    [self hideActivityIndicator];

}

@end
```

error:

```
fbconnect=1&skip_api_login=1&m=m&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Fpermissions.request%3F_path%3Dpermissions.request%26%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Fconnect%252Flogin_success.html%26display%3Dtouch%26type%3Duser_agent%26perms%3Dpublish_stream%26fbconnect%3D1%26from_login%3D1%26client_id%3D169265183116528&refsrc=http%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Flogin.php&cancel=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Flogin_success.html%3Ferror_reason%3Duser_denied%26error%3Daccess_denied%26error_description%3DThe%2Buser%2Bdenied%2Byour%2Brequest.&landing_serial=1&refid=9>
```

[image]

Comment: are you deploying for IOS6 or previous versions? . Could you give the error code?

Comment: with ios5 versions.. will provide the full code.. with the app id removed for safety reasons...

Comment: updated the question.. when i debug it get stuck at displayRequired function...

Comment: In edit scheme could you choose your scheme and enable guard malloc and zombie objects in the diagnostics tab. And updated question with exact error you are receiving.

Comment: same as before... I have updated the question...

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is nothing wrong with your code. I guess you are following Ray's tutorial which is an old one.

As you can see in you log `r%3Daccess_denied%26error_` access is denied by facebook. Now there may be various reasons for that. You need to find that out.

Simplest reason may be that you have not added or changed  your appID in your info.plist (In Supporting Files Folder under in info.plist in URL types add/change NSdictionary item make sure string is equal to your appID in your case it is either  `3D169265183116528` or `fb3D169265183116528`)

If thats not work I suggest you to look those two questions:

[Authentication Fails with Facebook App Installed (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257894/authentication-fails-with-facebook-app-installed-ios)

[iOS: Connect to Facebook without leaving the app for authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666523/ios-connect-to-facebook-without-leaving-the-app-for-authorization)

If I remember correct for grap api something like this should be in your plist
[image]

Comment: i dun see the URL types. but basically i added another item called NSDictionary item called appID and added the strings there..

Comment: see the picture in answer, I have just edited , from my old app that I used facebook graph api. Item 0 is the facebook appId

Comment: If it stills crashes you need to find problem or follow facebook's own tutorial for connection.https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

@lakesh I think [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/) will help you.