# can't switch users for FB connect on iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I have FB connect implemented in my app.  After battling with the FB app installed on a user's phone, I finally had success forcing the standard FB dialog and bypassing the FB app
(see [iOS: Connect to Facebook without leaving the app for authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666523/ios-connect-to-facebook-without-leaving-the-app-for-authorization))

My new problem is that I cannot seem to switch FB users within the app.  When  I click the "Login with Facebook" button from within my app, it quickly brings up the FB dialog, dissappears, and always logs me back in with the previous user  (meaning I have no way to switch FB users).

I've check both Safari and the FB app, and neither are logged in.  Do I have to tell FB to log out the previous user before a new user/pass is prompted?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation probably saves user's access token in NSUserDefaults. If it is so - you just need to delete it from NSUserDefaults any time there is a logout or you're switching users.

Also if needed you are able to deauthorize the user by making a DELETE graph API call to uid/permissions.

hope this helps

Comment: Adding some code or hint would work, (started development few days earlier only :/ )