# Using Facebook Integration Without Redirection in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

Is it possible to use Single Sign On without having to redirect them to the Facebook app?  I would like to simply display the WebView inside of the app.  ShareKit does not have the latest Facebook SDK.  After looking at the latest source for the Facebook SDK, it does not seem like it is possible.

Comment: There's an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666523/ios-connect-to-facebook-without-leaving-the-app-for-authorization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can login with `SSO` inside your App in the `WebView` itself.
If you don't want to authenticate via Safari, then go to `Facebook.m` file and see this method

```
- (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions {
}
```

and change safariAuth:NO in that code like this.

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  This definitely works.  Having said that, it looks like I am going to have to implement my own close button by changing their code as well (I can't close the dialog otherwise).  Thanks Facebook.